# JPA get request shows one day prior the date stored in Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller

I am using Spring-Boot for managing my Rest-API. I am storing a Date of birth in my postgreSQL DB as 02/10/1983 using the API with a json payload as `"dateOfBirth": "02/10/1983"`, and Its stored as it is, and the DB result is showing the exact date.
When I am fetching the record using Spring-Boot API call, the date is returned one day prior as 01/10/1983. Every date value is returned a day prior.
I also added a date to insert date using the below code:

```
long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();
Date currentDate=new Date(millis);
```

This also saves the date as **current date** in the DB but returning **One day prior the date** using rest API get calls.

Comment: maybe a timezone issue?

Comment: If it's a timezone issue, saving the current date should save a day prior to the DB right? or returning a manually stored DB saved date should be an exact date right? coz it is a select statement. Maybe am wrong, if so correct me if am

Comment: what is the datatype of the column that stores the date in the db?

Comment: Date column in DB,
java.sql.Date; in springboot, also @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") to format the date column

Comment: Looks like a time zone difference between your db and server. You can check the date you save in milliseconds and the date you retrieve in milliseconds. If they are the same you should adjust time zones.

Comment: Same throuble and reproducing only in tests. This is definitely not a timezone problem.